# Opening a Form from Another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a project called spreadsheetClient that contains client.cs. I would like to open up a spreadsheet GUI from a spreadsheetGUI.

```
SS.Program.Main(); // open up a spreadsheet GUI
Console.WriteLine("Spreadsheet is open.");
```

The code never gets to the Console.Writeline. In client.cs, how do I do other stuff while a GUI from another project is running at the same time?

```
public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            // Start an application context and run one form inside it
            DemoApplicationContext appContext = DemoApplicationContext.getAppContext();
            appContext.RunForm(new Form1());
            Application.Run(appContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to use multiple threads if you're going to launch it like that. but I'd just make a new Form1 from your project and call show, that way both can run on the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Run()` is not asynchronous. According to the MSDN documentation, this method "begins running a standard application message loop on the current thread."

Therefore, it will not return until the application is finished running and has terminated. In order to allow `Console.WriteLine("Spreadsheet is open.")` to run, you will need to call `Application.Run()` from a separate thread.

**EDIT:** To create and run a separate thread, you need to do this:

Create a new `System.Threading.Thread` like this:

```
var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate(){ 
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    // Start an application context and run one form inside it
    DemoApplicationContext appContext = DemoApplicationContext.getAppContext();
    appContext.RunForm(new Form1());
    Application.Run(appContext);
});
```

The delegate is an anonymous function that is passed directly into the thread. This tells the thread what to do when it starts up. Then you need to call `thread.Start();` in order to run the thread.